# My program cannot be built. I don't know why

Tags: java

This is my program that executes roots of a quadratic equation. Anybody know why I cannot run this program? I don't see errors. This is my code right here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class QuadEq {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner view = new Scanner(System.in);

        double a, b, c, x1, x2, x;

        a = view.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("What is your A value?");

        b = view.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("What is your B value?");

        c = view.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("What is your C value?");

        double delta = b * b - 4 * a * c;

        if(delta < 0) {
            System.out.println("The equation does not have solutions.");
        }

        if(delta == 0) {
            System.out.println("The equation has one solution: ");
            x = (-b) / (2 * a);
            System.out.println(x);
        }

        if(delta > 0) {
            System.out.println("The equation has two solutions: ");
            x1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
            x2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
            System.out.println(x1);
            System.out.println(x2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: So you are running your program and it seems to successfully start? Have you tried entering a number as per your `a = view.nextDouble();` line? It will wait until you have entered something and then press Enter.

Comment: `"I don't see errors."` - Then what's the problem?  What *do* you see when you try to compile or run this code?  "It doesn't work" isn't a problem description.

Comment: first thing to do .. make sure it really doesn't run. not just thinking it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably swap the prompts for input and the actual input method calls :

```
    System.out.println("What is your A value?");
    a = view.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("What is your B value?");
    b = view.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("What is your C value?");
    c = view.nextDouble();
```

Otherwise, your program would display no prompt for input until you input the first double.